# AD B2C ROPC user flow - Return Custom error meeages

Tags: error-handling, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, ropc

I am having a functionality to check the user is flagged with resetpassword or not during Sign-in

If the user is flagged with resetpassword, then I need to return error message saying "Reset the password and try again." else proceed with returning the JWT token.

I did not find a way to return custom error message from the ROPC user flow, can you please share some references or any solutions to this scenario.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/oauth2-error-technical-profile)?

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT Thank You, I will try this.